# GroupBy on Observable from AngularFireDatabase.list not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angularfire2, angularfire

I am unable to RxJs operator groupBy on observable created from `AngularFireDatabase.list("expenses").snapshotchanges(...)`

my firebase database has the following nodes

expenses

```
|_exp-1
    |_ amount:200
    |_ category:"cat-1"
    |_ date: "2018-06-18T19:00:00.000Z"

|_exp-2
    |_ amount:400
    |_ category:"cat-2"
    |_ date: "2018-06-18T19:00:00.000Z"

|_exp-3

    |_ amount:500
    |_ category:"cat-2"
    |_ date: "2018-06-18T19:00:00.000Z"

|_exp-4
    |_ amount:200
    |_ category:"cat-3"
    |_ date: "2018-06-18T19:00:00.000Z"
```

I am getting the data using `getExpenses()` function.
I am trying to groupby the resulting observable of this function in `groupExpensesbyCategory()`.
However I am getting an error on `data.category`

```
"Property 'category' does not exist on type 'any[]'. [2339]"
```

My getExpenses() function is working as expected and returning an observable of an array of 4 expense objects.

Why is groupBy not working on my observable. Please help.

```
getExpenses():Observable<any[]>{
return this.db.list('expenses')
.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(changes => 
    changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}))
  )
);
}

groupExpensesbyCategory():Observable<any[]>{

return this.getExpenses().pipe(
  groupBy(data=>data.category),
  mergeMap(group=>group.pipe(toArray()))
);
}
```

Edit:

As requested in the comments I am adding a screenshot of the result of

```
this.getExpenses().subscribe(console.log)
```

[image: Result of getExpenses()]

Comment: groupBy should work, can you verily what `this.getExpenses()` returns from above .

Comment: Just edited my question to add the result of this.getExpenses()

Comment: can you try like this  `Rx.Observable.from(this.getExpenses()).groupBy(c=>c.category)` let me know

Comment: Rx.Observable.from not working Cannot find name 'Rx'. [2304]. I also tried simply "from.this(this.getExpenses()).groupBy(c=>c.category)" but it still not recognising category.

Comment: `Rx.Observable` not required remove it, u can simply include `import { from } from 'rxjs/observable/from';` use `from(this.getExpenses()).groupBy(c=>c.category)`

Comment: yes I have imported all the mentioned operators already

Comment: already tried from after importing the from operator

Comment: Well I’ve created a sample locally  it works for me let me share it up with you .

Comment: Can you provide us a stackblitz example?

Comment: In `getExpenses()` you map your return value to `{ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val()}`. I guess `c.payload.val()` is not containing the `category` property. Can you log `c.payload.val()`?

Comment: @arjukhan check this working sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-groupby-with-sum-v3vs2b . check console for output.

Comment: @supercool this.getExpenses().groupBy(data=>data.category) is now working after I changed the return type of getExpenses from Observable<any[]> to Observable<any>. But when mergeMap and toArray is applied on the groupedobservable the groupExpensesbyCategory() stops emitting any values